# How to use data from input as parameter referencing an existing object instance?

Tags: python, class, oop, input

This is my first ever stackoverflow post and I'm also a beginner coder, so please excuse any ignorance here. I've been racking my brain all day trying out figure out what I imagine is something simple.

I am working on a small OOP based program to view and modify inventory. I am stuck at trying to take input from a user and applying it to a class method as the object parameter.

Very simply put, this is what I am trying to do, but it is failing because the value from input is a **string** and the method expects an **object name**.

```
class_instance.class_method(input())
```

More in depth.. Here is the inventory class, and you can see that the `remove_product` method expects an object instance.

```
class Inventory(): 

# Instantiate object and give functionality to printing object
def __init__(self):
    self.inventory_summary = {}
    self.inventory_total = 0
    self.products = []

# Remove product objects from inventory and adjust value    
def remove_product(self,product):
    print("\n{} removed from inventory.".format(product.ID))
    self.products.remove(product.ID)
    self.inventory_total -= product.total_value
    del self.inventory_summary[product.ID]
    print("Current inventory of products: {}".format(self.products))
    print("Updated inventory total: ${}".format(self.inventory_total))
```

In my application, I have the product list displayed as a dictionary. When prompted to delete a product from the inventory, I would like the user to be able to type `product1` (variable name of instance of **Product** class) to pass `product1` to the inventory class to be removed.

Is this possible (and efficient/practical/ethical)? TYIA to anyone willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need some kind of index to reffer or consider parsing input string.

```
# Inefficient
def remove_product(self, user_input): 'milk'
   for product in self.products:
       if user_input == product.name:
            ...
```

```
# If you are showing products with IDs, eg. "1x Soap (#1), 3x Milk (#4)" for user to reffer
def remove_product(self, user_input): # '3'
   if int(user_input) in self.products:
        ...
```

You could also (do not, it's dangerous) use eval.

```
def remove_product(self, user_input): # '3'
   product_obj = eval(user_input)() # for 'milk' it would create object of milk class

   # search for your product type and delete
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little loopy, so apologies if I'm missing something very obvious (I had to read it a few times, but I think I understand).

For starters, your class code isn't set up for what you want to do. I struggle a little with classes, so believe me I get it, but here is how you would code and use the class as you've set it up:

```
# the class
class Inventory:
# Instantiate object and give functionality to printing object
    def __init__(self, inventory_summary, inventory_total, products):
        self.inventory_summary = inventory_summary
        self.inventory_total = inventory_total
        self.products = products

# The usage
def main():
    summary = {"1":"summary"}
    total = 10
    products = ["products"]
    my_inventory = Inventory(summary, total, products)
    print(my_inventory.inventory_summary)
    print(my_inventory.inventory_total)
    print(my_inventory.products)
```

output:

```
> {'1': 'summary'} 
> 10 
> ['products']
```

However, it sounds like you want to create a global class variable, which would be achieved like this (which people smarter than me have told me is wrong to do, but I still use):

```
def main():
    Inventory.defining_class(Inventory)
    print(Inventory.inventory_summary)
    print(Inventory.inventory_total)
    print(Inventory.products)

class Inventory:
# Instantiate object and give functionality to printing object
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def defining_class(self):
        self.inventory_summary = {}
        self.inventory_total = 0
        self.products = []
```

output:

```
> {}
> 0
> []
```

Given my understanding, this should fix the problem you have.